# Download audio files from url

Tags: python, pywin32, wininet

I want to download an audio file from a url and split them into separate files of a certain size (so that one part of the program plays audio and the other downloads them).

**Please don't say that there are other libraries for this, I have such a task, so I need to use win32inet**

I've written some code that downloads and splits files that does this, it's far from perfect, but it does the job, but there are a few issues:

**1)** Only the first downloaded file is played, so far how many have been downloaded, the others give an error
**2)** The file contains the size of the full audio and not the part that should be downloaded (That is, the full audio has a time of 07:18, and when I download a part of this file, I would like the file to have a time that is equivalent to the size of the file, but the file contains the full time of 07:18)

I suspect that the problem is that important information about the file is contained in the first bytes of the file, but how can I implement this for my task?

```
def splitSound2Files():
 curDir = os.getcwd()
 fileCounter = 0
 buff = [] 
 buffSize = 1024*250
 hInet = win32inet.InternetOpen('HTTPGET',0x00000001,'','',0)
 hUrl = win32inet.InternetOpenUrl(hInet, getAudioURL(), '', 0, 0)
 while True:
    f = open(curDir+'\\Beethoven\\'+str(fileCounter)+'.mp3', 'wb')
    buff = win32inet.InternetReadFile(hUrl,buffSize)
    f.write(buff)
    if len(buff) != buffSize:
        break
    fileCounter = fileCounter + 1
 win32inet.InternetCloseHandle(hUrl)
 win32inet.InternetCloseHandle(hInet)
```

Comment: What you want needs special knowledge about or a good library for the audio format used (mp3 as it seems). A simpler approach could be, depending on the way you play the files, to make the files with the audio parts look like one large file for the audio player.

Comment: Download the whole file with `win32inet` as it is your requirement. Then snip the audio as your desired timestamp

Comment: where is the `getAudioURL()` defined or what is it ?

Comment: the question needs sufficient code for a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)